# Camel + pollEnrich from bean

Tags: apache-camel

How do i use pollEnrich with Bean in Apache Camel?

I tried using this but getting excetion "You cannot consume from a bean endpoint" in this case, i am calling rest api but client has provided jar file so i need to call bean and get additional information.

```
from("quartz2://tsTimer?cron=" + cron + "&trigger.timeZone=" + timezone)
        .bean(tradingService)
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.setProperty("fileName","input-"  + dateFormat.format(new Date()) + ".xml");
            }
        })
        .pollEnrich("bean:tradingService", new AggregationStrategy() {

            @Override
            public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
                System.out.println("oldExchange : " + oldExchange +" newExchange : " + newExchange);
                return null;
            }
        })
        .marshal().jacksonxml(true)
        .wireTap("file:" + auditDir + "/?fileName=${header.fileName}")
        //split or merge
        .to("xslt:trans.xslt")
        .to(outQueue)
        .to("log:org.ts.tradingservice.camel?level=INFO&showBody=true")
        .end();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `enrich` which is for using the producer side, eg `enrich(...)`. You can use that if you need to *merge* the data together via the aggregation strategy. However if you just want to result/output of the bean then use a plain `to` instead, of if the bean method is a `void` method.